# Struggling with AWS Cloud9 and pip install additional python packages

Tags: cloud9, aws-cloud9

Hey Cloud9ers out there,

I am struggling with the new AWS Cloud9 IDE right at the beginning by installing missing packages. I tried pip install but without any success.

I'd like to install pandas!

Comment: import sys
print('Hello, World!')
print('The sum of 2 and 3 is 5.')
sum = int(sys.argv[1]) + int(sys.argv[2])

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual environment and try

```
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv v-env
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip install pandas
deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions provided here worked well for me: [Install pip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-python.html#sample-python-sdk)